# Does the embedding of the Grassmannian in the projectivization of the exterior algebra require the axiom of choice?

Tags: axiom-of-choice, projective-space, grassmannian

According to [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian) for the Grassmannian, the embedding in the projectivization of the exterior algebra of $V$ requires the choice of, for every r-dimensional subspace, a basis for that space. The point in $P(\Lambda (V))$ is associated with the equivalence class of the wedge product of the basis vectors (or at least that's how I've been thinking about it). The choice of basis vectors requires a function from each subspace to a set of basis vectors, right? And the existence of such a function is only permitted by the axiom of choice, right? Or is there an alternate construction where this choice is unnecessary?

Comment: AC is unnecessary, since any basis of $W\subseteq V$ will give the same point of $\Bbb{P}(\bigwedge V)$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown ah, makes sense. You might as well make that an answer.